# Loading ordnance survey raster ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I have connected to the correct folder on ArcCatalog.

Only the .tif files show on my ArcCatalog tree, but the .tlw files are in that folder too. How do I create a raster layer with this data?

I have tried to drag these over to ArcMap but it says the data is not georeferenced.

There are hundreds of tiles, is having them both in the same folder enough? How else do I get the program to recognise them as the georeferences for my raster .tif tiles?

Comment: It will understand .tww or .tifw. Make a copy of .tlw to .tww and see if it works.

Comment: Is this particular "ordnance survey raster" data available as open data to download so that we can test and advise?